# POST to a Rails API using Rails and HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, httparty, rails-api

I'm sorry if this seems a pretty basic question, but I'm pretty new at this too, so... I'm having problems with basic operations in an application that uses an API (both on rails), **but let's say that for now all I wanna do is create a record in the db of the API through a request from the application.**

So this is what I've done so far:

- For the API I used the [rails-api gem](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api).
- For the app that consume the API I used the [HTTParty gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty).

For the API I followed this tutorial [railscasts.com: the rails api-gem](http://media.railscasts.com/assets/episodes/videos/348-the-rails-api-gem.mp4), and I made the `City` model trough `rails g scaffold City name:string description:string` command.

The resulting controller is this:

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_city, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /cities
  # GET /cities.json
  def index
    @cities = City.all

    render json: @cities
  end

  # GET /cities/1
  # GET /cities/1.json
  def show
    render json: @city
  end

  # POST /cities
  # POST /cities.json
  def create
    @city = City.new(city_params)

    if @city.save
      render json: @city, status: :created, location: @city
    else
      render json: @city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /cities/1
  # PATCH/PUT /cities/1.json
  def update
    @city = City.find(params[:id])

    if @city.update(city_params)
      head :no_content
    else
      render json: @city.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cities/1
  # DELETE /cities/1.json
  def destroy
    @city.destroy

    head :no_content
  end

  private

    def set_city
      @city = City.find(params[:id])
    end

    def city_params
      params.require(:city).permit(:name, :description)
    end
end
```

Notice the routes for the cities are:

```
cities GET    /cities(.:format)     cities#index
       POST   /cities(.:format)     cities#create
  city GET    /cities/:id(.:format) cities#show
       PATCH  /cities/:id(.:format) cities#update
       PUT    /cities/:id(.:format) cities#update
       DELETE /cities/:id(.:format) cities#destroy
```

Now, in the app that will consume the API services I made the cities controller trough `rails g controller cities index new show edit destroy` command, and I put some code trying to create a record trough the API, but it doesn't do a thing.

The code of the controller is:

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

  def new
    @result = HTTParty.post('url_of_my_api_on_heroku/cities', :body => {:name => 'New York', :description => 'ABC'}.to_json, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a City record (where the name is 'New York' and description is "ABC") when I go to the new view on my app (I'm doing this to test only), but when I go to the `new` view of cities in my app, the API deployed on Heroku always returns an empty hash where it return the hash of cities, so, I don't know if I have something wrong on the API, on the app that consumes the API, or in both of them, somebody can tell me how to make this work?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CitiesController, we are requiring :city in 'city_params'

```
def city_params
  params.require(:city).permit(:name, :description)
end
```

But when calling the api, we missed passing :city

```
def new
  @result = HTTParty.post('url_of_my_api_on_heroku/cities', :body => {:name => 'New York', :description => 'ABC'}.to_json, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
end
```

So, it should be:

```
def new
  @result = HTTParty.post('url_of_my_api_on_heroku/cities', :body => {:city => {:name => 'New York', :description => 'ABC'}}.to_json, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
end
```